# What is "fitness benefits" here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

"In some cases, the habitat that provides the best opportunity for survival may not be the same habitat as the one that provides for highest reproductive capacity because of requirements specific to the reproductive period. Thus, individuals of many resident species, confronted with the **fitness benefits** of control over a productive breeding site, may be forced to balance costs in the form of **lower nonbreeding survivorship** by remaining in the specific habitat where highest breeding success occurs."

Q1. What is "fitness benefits" here? Is it about some benefits from fitness which means 'health' or something?

Q2. What does "lower nonbreeding survivorship" mean here? It doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: When asking questions about a quote, please provide the source.

Comment: I don't think this question is really about learning English. The comprehension problem is probably much the same for a non-Anglophone armed with a dictionary as for the average native speaker. That's to say, it's the biological / evolutionary ***concepts*** that cause problems, rather than the actual words. I assume anyone even *attempting* to read such text would understand what, say, "evolutionary **fitness**" is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph is drawing a distinction between two environments (habitats) in which any species might find itself and the choice that faces that species as a result.

The first environment is that which offers the best conditions for breeding (highest reproductive capacity).

The second environment is that which offers the best conditions for survival (lower non-breeding survivorship).

So the species may have to choose between breeding in a more challenging habitat or non-breeding in a safer habitat.

An example might be this:

Adult animals might find enough food for survival within easy access in a habitat that did not expose them to predators or other dangers.

But to feed offspring, they might need to search for food over a greater area - or in different conditions - that did expose them to predators or other dangers.

They would then need to choose between staying safe without procreating successfully, or facing the dangers involved in seeking food for their offspring.

In purely human terms, this is the situation often faced by couples. They are likely to be more financially secure when childless and both partners are employed. Financial strains are likely to be much tougher when just one partner brings in money and the other cares for children.

Comment: It's difficult to know exactly how the term **fitness benefits** is being used in this context. It would appear to be academic jargon referring to the advantages to a/the species in general, both of survival and of successful procreation in particular circumstances/habitats/environments..

Answer (score 1):

The concept of survival of the fittest is involved here. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_of_the_fittest for a full explanation. So if you have access to a better breeding site it improves your chances of reproducing and hence improves the survival of your genes. However that place may be also alter their chances of survival without breeding.

I would have to say this is a very difficult passage which needs quite a bit of background and even then I am not really sure what the author is trying to convey.